# Ambiguous call services.Configure<AppSettings>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Am trying to using the following in my Startup.cs to load the some values from the AppSettings.cs. I used the same method in a previous project with no issues.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        services.AddMvc();

        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
    }
```

However am now getting the following error:

> Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure<TOptions>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration)` and
>   `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure<TOptions>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration)`

It appears I have a duplicate / incompatible dependency but I can find find it. Below is my project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0",
    "tessitura.nuget": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net462": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Web": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Web.Services": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Have looked at a number of similar posts but not yet found a solution. Can anyone please help as this is driving me nuts?

Thanks

**Edit**

Tried commenting out "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions", which seemed to make Visual Studio happy but when I tried to run it was presenting with the following error:
[image]

Comment: Do you not get an underline beneath the ambiguous code in the editor?  If so pressing ctrl .  would usually present actions to rectify, such as using a fully qualified name. If not,  try right clicking solution, clean and restart vs. I can't see it being a dependency issue as they would have different namespaces.

Comment: If I leave "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" uncommented then Yes do get a line under the Configure<AppSettings> bit but Ctrl. doesn't offer any solutions. If I comment out the dependency then the line disappears but I get the 500 error when I run it.

Comment: Don't mix ancient beta versions of ASP.NET Core with release versions! They have completely different package names. Also stop using tutorials/blogs which are older than July 2016, they are too outdated and use these ancient package names. `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core": "6.0.0-rc1-final",     "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "6.0.0-rc1-final",` should be `"Microsoft.AspNetcore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.0", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "1.0.0",` or better, use 1.0.3. Versions lower than 1.0.3 are know to be vulnerable

Comment: Why the down vote? It's a legitimate question. Why they may be another question which similar clearly I didn't find it in the day I lost working on this problem so maybe this might help someone else get to the solution faster. However the down vote just prompts me to delete the whole post, which doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Long winded but the best and most straight forward approach is to just comment out parts of the project file until you code works and you know which dependency is causing the problem.

Comment: Did try this. See Edit for result.